# MS Access: Backstage - image not displaying

Tags: ms-access-2010

I created my own backstage tab and want to display images. I can display "imageMso" images but not an image located on my hard drive. Is my XML code wrong? What am I missing. Thank you.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<backstage> 
    <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="SaveObjectAs" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="FileSaveAsCurrentFileFormat" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="FileCloseDatabase" visible="true"/> 
    <tab idMso ="TabInfo" visible="false"/>    
    <tab idMso ="TabRecent" visible="false"/> 
    <tab idMso ="TabNew" visible="false"/> 
    <tab idMso ="TabPrint" visible="false"/> 
    <tab idMso ="TabShare" visible="false"/> 
    <tab idMso ="TabHelp" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="true"/> 
    <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/> 
    <tab  id="Tab1" label="My Tab">
        <firstColumn>
            <group id="myGroup" style="normal" label="ImageControl:">
                <topItems>
                    <layoutContainer id="layInfo1" layoutChildren="horizontal" align="topLeft">
                        <imageControl id="img1" imageMso="AppointmentColorDialog"/>
                        <labelControl id="lbl1" label="Image 1"/>
                    </layoutContainer>
                    <layoutContainer id="layInfo2" layoutChildren="horizontal" align="topLeft">
                        <imageControl id="img2" imageMso="AppointmentColorDialog"/>
                        <labelControl id="lbl2" label="Image 2"/>
                    </layoutContainer>
                    <layoutContainer id="layInfo3" layoutChildren="horizontal" align="topLeft">
                        <imageControl id="img3" image="C:\Projects\Quoting\BEC\Logo.bmp"/>
                        <labelControl id="lbl3" label="Image 3"/>
                    </layoutContainer>
                </topItems>
            </group>
        </firstColumn>
    </tab>
</backstage>
```

[image]

Comment: Change screenshot to text version for Your code;

Comment: Added code. So, please help me... Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use the same way for images as for main ribbon, callback function `getImage="GetImages"`? I monited all disk activity, Access even don't try to search file with name after `image=`

Comment: I was able to use callback function. Still don't know why image="logo.bmp" would not work.